# WiX Burn Bootstrapper does not call OnDetectRelatedBundle

Tags: c#, wix, windows-installer, burn

I have a Bundle with several ExePackage and MsiPackage Elements. It is a perMachine package (all the Msi and Exe Packages are perMachine or ForcePerMachine)
I wrote a custom BA with C#;

installing it works fine,modifying, uninstalling, and the Bundle registered correctly as per log:

```
[06F8:0F3C][2015-10-07T11:12:32]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{eb3fd6f6-0cb2-4999-84e9-7d71f5ab1551}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
[06F8:0F3C][2015-10-07T11:12:32]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{eb3fd6f6-0cb2-4999-84e9-7d71f5ab1551}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
```

But if I start the Setup.exe again, from my understanding, when detect() is called, OnDetectRelatedBundle should fire - which it doesn't. (afaik it should log, furthermore I added my own Engine.Log entry which does not fire)

upon investigation of the registry (and sniffing around in the source code)
I found out that the key is under \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft...

Because I opened the same bundle, the same UpgradeCode should be used.

Questions:

Is it ok that the registration is on the Wownode, and does the detection of the related bundles also look upon the Wownode? 
(I don't have 3.10 Source Code because I couldn't find the branch, but from the 3.8 Code the following const regarding writing/reading the registry seemed intriguing:

```
const LPCWSTR BURN_REGISTRATION_REGISTRY_UNINSTALL_KEY = L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall";
```

)

What else could I have missed regarding the related bundle detection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Burn engine will never call `OnDetectRelatedBundle` for the currently executing bundle, because it's not a related bundle - it's *the* bundle. The `fInstalled` parameter of `OnDetectBegin` will tell you if the bundle is installed or not.

The source code is at https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3.  The master branch always has the code for the latest release.

Comment: thanks a lot! I thought that relatedbundle fired because i tested it several times; probably whenever it worked i rebuilded to get small changes in the dlls to be in the bundle, thus making it related.